# How do I change the text of a System.Windows.Forms.Label from a public static void button_click event?

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, eventhandler

More details:

Assume I am creating a form and a button and a label in the main function, and I want the label text to change when I click on the button. I am getting an error that the label is outside of the scope. My button_click method can't reach the label for some reason. Obviously I am not doing this the right way because I am clearly misunderstanding something. But how would I go about doing this the proper way?

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do and how I'm currently attempting to do it. Suppose I have this and everything can compile except for **label.Text = "New Text"**:

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace example {
    class demo {
        public static void Main(String[] args){
            Form form = new Form();
            Label label = new Label();
            label.Text = "Initial Text";
            Button button = new Button();
            button.Click += button_click;
            form.Controls.Add(button);
            form.ShowDialog();
        }

        public static void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e){
            label.Text = "New Text";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing form.Controls.Add(label);

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with the code that you've posted.

1. Scope
2. The label hasn't been added to the form.

Try the following:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace example
{
    class demo
    {
        private static Form _form1 = null;

        static void Main()
        {
            //create new instance
            _form1 = new Form();

            //set value
            _form1.Text = "Demo";

            //create new instance
            Label label1 = new Label();
            label1.Location = new Point(10,10);
            label1.Name = "label1";
           
            //set value
            label1.Text = "Initial Text";

            //add to form
            _form1.Controls.Add(label1);

            //create new instance
            Button button1 = new Button();

            //subscribe to event(s)
            button1.Click += Button1_Click;

            //set value
            button1.Location = new Point(10, 50);
            button1.Name = "button1";
            button1.Size = new Size(75, 30);
            button1.Text = "Click Me";

            //add to form
            _form1.Controls.Add(button1);

            //show
            _form1.ShowDialog();
        }

        private static void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //set value
            _form1.Controls["label1"].Text = "New Text";
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: `string[] args` in `static void Main(string[] args)` is unnecessary since you aren't passing any arguments.

Writing code for a Form like this is tedious, you may consider using [Visual Studio Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/).

**Resources**:

- [Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables)